# TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=0 when i use responsive ads

Tags: adsense

i have responsive ads set for Adsense

I am getting the error:

uncaught exception: TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=0

on every page that has this code

```
<style type="text/css">
.adslot_2 { display:inline-block;width: 336px; height: 280px;}
@media (max-width: 336px) { .adslot_2 { width: 300px; height: 250px; } }
@media (min-width: 500px) { .adslot_2 { display: none; } }
</style>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle adslot_2" data-ad-client="removed for security purpose" data-ad-slot="removed for security purpose" data-ad-format="rectangle"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

i tried tampering with the code a lot but still getting the same error
note that i have other responsive ad units  with different codes that are not showing this error so i am 100% sure the problem is with the code itself

my objective is to hide the ad from desktop and show it on mobile devices

what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are (basically) two different methods of responsive ad unit "sizing" in Google AdSense.

- "*Automatic sizing based on the space available*" with
  `data-ad-format`. See [**About responsive ad units**](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689) page.
- "*Exact
  ad unit size per screen width*" with `@media` queries. See [**How to
  modify your responsive ad code**](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6307124) page. (You'll find there are "variations",
  different implementations of this method.)

The first one is automatic, the second is "manual".

Usually no method can be automatic and manual at the same time, because there will be a conflict between the two, and I think your code should work fine if you remove `data-ad-format="rectangle"`.

If that works for you, please check again "My ads" > "Ad units" page in your Google AdSense dashboard, and make sure this **ad unit ID** (`data-ad-slot`) is listed as "Responsive" - none of the two methods should be used with fixed sized ad units.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much for your answer :)
i tried to give an upvote for your answer but still dont have enough reputation as i joined yesterday

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. I noticed that it was because of the banners which had been made invisible based on the size of screen. A solution was to rename the "adsbygoogle" class (I went for 'ADSENSE') to make sure the adsense script wouldn't do anything with the banners before I remove them from the DOM if they were not visible once the stylesheet had been loaded (hence the 'load' event):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 let matches = document.querySelectorAll("ins.ADSENSE");

        Array.from(matches).forEach((element) => {
            let parentElement = element.parentElement;
            if (window.getComputedStyle(parentElement).getPropertyValue("display") === "none")  { 
                element.remove(); 
            } else {
            element.classList.remove("ADSENSE");
            element.classList.add("adsbygoogle");
                (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); 
            }
        });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

replace:

```js
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
```

with:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function (){
         (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
         })
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?