# Uncaught TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=0

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api, elementor

I am using the following code to insert Google Ads at three slots on my website. However, I am getting the following error:

`Uncaught TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=0`

```
<div align="center">
<!-- Sidebar Ads -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="(ad-client-xxxxx)"
     data-ad-slot="(xxxxx)"
     data-ad-format="auto"
     data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
</div>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

I tried the solution described in the following stack overflow question:

[TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=0 when i use responsive ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50827616/tagerror-adsbygoogle-push-error-no-slot-size-for-availablewidth-0-when-i-use)

However, that didn't seem to help!

Answer (score 0):

try to set this

```
window.onload = function() {
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
}
```

instead of `(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});`
It work for me